# Is there an easy method to tidy up a Database Column by separating the place and the post code?

Tags: sql, informix

I currently have this problem:
I own a database with different columns like name, adress, place and post code. Unfortunately I have some messy entries where the post code is empty but the place is built like this: PLACE POST CODE.
Is there a way to clean this mess up? Or do I have to do it manually?

The database is built on Informix.

Sample Data:

**Customer Number**:  12315 (Auto Incremental)

**Name**           :  Best Machines (Company Name)

**Other Names**    :  Germany

**Street Adress**  :  Best Road in Town No. 15

**Post Code**      :  51691

**Name of Place**  :  Best City   HERE IS THE PROBLEM: Because some are saved like Best City POSTCODE even though there are two separate Columns ( i.e. Best City 51691)

**Country**        :  Best Country

Thanks in advance,

Gusdl

Comment: Can you post some sample data please?

Comment: @rohitvats Sorry! Tried to add some now. Hopefully it makes it more clear

Comment: Is the data like Best City 51691 only or they can be like 51691 Best City?

Comment: It's only Best City 51691. There is no case of 51691 Best City

Comment: Which version of Informix are you using? Does it support regular expressions? Alternatively, is the postcode always the last five characters of the **Name of Place** column? Are all the columns you mentioned defined in the same database table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could query the rows that matches "*" + POST CODE and update the place with PLACE - POST CODE

This update makes this

```
update name_of_table set place = substr(place, 1, length(place)-length(post_code))
 where place matches "*" || post_code
```

I tested in Informix 12.10 and makes what you want

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked exactly as I wanted it to be :)